# Trouble with selector

Tags: css

I'm fiddling with a Wordpress site and created a class of element called .email for the front page call to action.

When I use .class as a selector the changes I make are not coming through. They do when I use inspect element on Chrome though.

To my knowledge (I'm not a developer) I can simply use .someclass and it will select it globally. This does not appear to be working here though.

In choosing what code to display for this question I'm really not sure. The site is here: tinyurl.com/m562wgd

In the very middle of the page there is an email address that I would like to apply styling to but cannot select it with .email.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="front-call-to-action">

                <div class="front-button">

    <a class="phonenumber" href="" >
                    Call: 647.832.8626              </a> 

                <!--20130607 Gavin added email address to CTA -->
                <br />
                <a class="email" href="mailto:gavin.patchwood@gmail.com">gavin.patchwood@gmail.com</a>


            </div>
            </div>
```

and here is the CSS I was trying with:

```
.email {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think your link is working, also can you please post the relevant code or create a simplified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @Adrift the link is working for me? Have added code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the issue! You used styles inside media queries. That is why it isn't working. You must close media queries block in order to make it work.

http://patchwood.ca/wp-content/themes/orbit/style.css?ver=3.5.1

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #logo img {
    height: auto;
    width: 50%;
}
.footer-box {
    display: none;
    }
.email {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    }
```

Fixed CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #logo img {
    height: auto;
    width: 50%;
}
.footer-box {
    display: none;
    }
}
.email {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

Edit:

Close your media queries block for `max-width:600px` as well

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  /* responsive menu*/
  .main-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .tinynav {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
  .search-page {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #logo,
  #main-navigation,
  #content,
  aside,
  .footer-box,
  .footer-copy,
   .footer-credit,
  #front-text-feature {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 97.91666666666666%;
    margin: 0 1.0416666666666665%;
  }
  .footer-box {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 5%;
  }
  #front-slide,
  .front-box {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 97.91666666666666%;
    margin: 0 1.0416666666666665%;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
  }
  #front-text-feature,
  #front-slide {
    padding: 12px 0;
  }
  #front-boxes,
  .front-features {
    margin-bottom: 24px;
  }
  .social-icons ul {
    margin: 12px 0 12px 0;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
  }
  .footer-copy {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .footer-credit {
    margin-top: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}
} //Add this extra block
```

Answer (score 2):

The class is there, but no styles are showing up. That could mean a typo or just that the styles aren't there to begin with.

Once the styles show up in the inspector, make sure that a selector with higher specificity isn't overriding your styles. If it is, you have to make your selector more specific than what is overriding it.

Answer (score 1):

Try
     `a.email {
     font-style: italic;
     font-size: 0.8em;
     }`

I haven't used css in a while but I think another solution may be

```
#email {
font-style: italic;
font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

Then in your html use

```
<a id="email" href="mailto:gavin.patchwood@gmail.com">gavin.patchwood@gmail.com</a>
```

I personally like using IDs over the classes because it is more straightforward to me, but it may not always be the best solution.

Comment: That was my backup, thanks for taking the time to answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to select it with:

```
#front-text-feature .front-call-to-action .email { 
  some style here
}
```

It's because in CSS more specific selector is more important. In your current code the .email link is styled by:

```
#front-text-feature .front-call-to-action a {
  styling code 
}
```

So it's more important for a browser to use this style than just .email